# Binding properties from two user controls which have the same parent

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

**Hello everyone :D**

I am currently developing an "XML editor" WPF application which contains two layouts:

- A **menu bar** where the user can select an XML path (File > Open),
- An **editor panel** which loads and displays XML content in a pre-defined format.

Here is the overall architecture :

[image: Overall architecture]

The following lines only show relevant files, but let me know if you need more details. There is no model in my MVVM software in order to give you a minimum number of files.

In *MainWindow.xaml*:

```
<Window x:Class="Software.MainWindow"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Software"
    xmlns:v="clr-namespace:Software.Views"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Software.ViewModels"
    ...>
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>

<Grid>
    <DockPanel>
        <v:MenuBar x:Name="MenuBar" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Panel.ZIndex="1"/>
        <v:Editor x:Name="Editor" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

In *MainWindow*:

```
namespace Software
{
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainViewModel mainViewModel = new MainViewModel();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MenuBar.DataContext = mainViewModel.MenuViewModel;
        Editor.DataContext = mainViewModel.EditViewModel;
    }

    private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        mainViewModel.MenuViewModel.selectXmlFile();
    }
}
}
```

In *MainViewModel*:

```
namespace Software.Views
{
public class MainViewModel
{
    public MenuBarViewModel MenuViewModel;
    public EditorViewModel EditViewModel;

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        MenuViewModel = new MenuBarViewModel();
        EditViewModel = new EditorViewModel();
    }
}
}
```

In *MenuBar.xaml*:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SmsReader.Views.MenuBar"
         xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:SmsReader.ViewModels"
         ...>
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <vm:MenuBarViewModel />
</UserControl.DataContext>

<Menu>
    <MenuItem Header="File" >
        <MenuItem Header="Open" Click="MenuItem_Click"/>
        <Separator Margin="10, 0"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Other"/>
    </MenuItem>

    <MenuItem Header="Other"/>
</Menu>
</UserControl>
```

In *MenuBar*:

```
namespace Software.Views
{
public partial class MenuBar : UserControl
{
    public MenuBar()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MenuXmlPath = ((MenuBarViewModel) DataContext).getXmlFile();
    }
}
}
```

In *MenuBarViewModel*:

```
namespace Software.ViewModels
{
    public class MenuBarViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string xmlPath;
        public string XmlPath
        {
            get { return xmlPath; }
            set { xmlPath = value; Fire("XmlPath"); }
        }

        public void selectXmlFile()
        {
            OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            dialog.Filter = "XML files (*.xml)|*.xml|All files (*)|*.*";
            XmlPath = (dialog.ShowDialog() == true) ? dialog.FileName : "";
        }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void Fire(string name) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

In *EditorViewModel*:

```
namespace Software.ViewModels
{
public class EditorViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string xmlSource;
    public string XmlSource
    {
        get { return xmlSource; }
        set { xmlSource = value; Fire("XmlSource"); update(value); }
    }

    public void update(string xmlSource)
    {
        // Load XML data and display into the editor panel
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void Fire(string name) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
}
}
```

I would like to link the property "XmlSource" to "XmlPath". What is the most elegant way to implement this?

Any advice concerning the architecture will be welcomed btw!
**Thank you in advance :)**

Comment: You should read a lot more about MVVM, INotifyPropertyChanged, ICommand and how binding works between view and viewmodel

Comment: If two properties should be the same, you should consider making them the same instead of linking them. Like an `XmlSourceViewModel` that contains the `XmlSource` (or `XmlPath`, just use one name). Then just place the same instance of this new class inside both, the `MenuViewModel` and `EditViewModel`. There are many other ways if you don't like this approach or if it doesn't really reflect your business logic. Sir Rufo is right, you should learn some more concepts. It's not really common to design a `ViewModel` as a `DependencyObject`. Using `INotifyPropertyChanged` is much more common.

Comment: Very much agree with @Sir Rufo, your entire architecture is wrong here and you'll save yourself a hell of a lot of headaches down the track switching to MVVM now while you still can.

Comment: You're right, I've reviewed my architecture following the standard design pattern and it seems more simple.